# IBM MQ and Kafka Integration

Tags: apache-kafka, ibm-mq, apache-kafka-connect

i am working on a solution where the client already own an iBM MQ so i need to integrate Kafka to it. i would need to fetch data from a IBM MQ and push it to kafka topic for further processing. I would request experts to answer my query and the best way it can be done.

if I develop a Kafka connect to fetch data from IBM MQ then it is will incurred into licenses.. may be we client wont agree for the license cost.

**Intend :** to build a solution without license if possible.

Kindly suggest if that can done in any Open source way for this implementation.

i have tried to look for many blogs but they say it should be done using Kafka connect which is from confluent.

Answer (score 2):

Kafka Connect itself is not from Confluent. [Kafka Connect is an API as a part of Apache Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connectapi). Kafka Connect is definitely the preferred way to integrate Kafka with other systems.

There are different connector plugins available, with varying licences and support available. There are two connectors for IBM MQ that I could find :

- https://github.com/ibm-messaging/kafka-connect-mq-source - Apache 2.0, from IBM
- https://www.confluent.io/connector/kafka-connect-ibm-mq/ - commercial licence from Confluent